# How to count records for each day in a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.2

I have a voting system. Each vote has a score.

I want to be able to count how many votes were made per day?

The code below adds the scores of each vote for each day and returns a hash with the total and the date as a key:

```
ratings = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now).group("created_at").select("created_at, sum(score) as total_score")
ratings.each_with_object({}) do |rating, scores|
 scores[rating.created_at.to_date] = rating.total_score
end
```

I want to be able to count how many votes were made on each day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

You can do what you want using a much nicer syntax:

```
from = start.beginning_of_day
to   = Time.zone.now
Rating.group('date(created_at)').where(created_at: from .. to).count(:score)
```

This will return a hash having the date(created_at) as a key and count(:score) as value, for each day.

Example: 
    { "2014-01-21" => 100, "2014-01-22" => 1213 }

The corresponding SQL is:

```
SELECT COUNT("ratings"."score") AS count_score, date(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM "ratings" WHERE ("ratings"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-01-21' AND '2014-01-24') GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

Comment: I need to count and not sum though?

Comment: In your question you used sum. I will change the answer to use count.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding MySQL query would be

```
SELECT date(created_at) as date, count(*) as count FROM `ratings` WHERE (created_at between '2014-01-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-24 08:16:46') GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

The Rails version is:

```
start_date = Date.parse("2014-01-21").beginning_of_day
end_time = Time.zone.now
Rating.group('date(created_at)').select('date(created_at) as date, count(*) as count').where(["created_at between ? AND ?", start_time, end_time])
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the date-range, lemme correct the answer in a min

Comment: this question have tag `postgresql-9.2`

Comment: @Monk_Code Query looks like it'd run in Pg fine too, you just have to fix the weird-ass MySQL quoting of identifiers, removing the backticks around `ratings` or replacing them with ANSI SQL standard double quotes (`"ratings"`)